# How to read and display particular xml data in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I just want know which game is play.

one url is -> wwww.something.com/data.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Cricket>
   <WC Group="A" Day="Sunday">
      <DayMatch>Aus Vs Ind</DayMatch>
      <NightMatch>Ban Vs S A</Night>
   </WC>
   <WC Group="A" Day="Monday">
      <DayMatch>Ind Vs Ban</DayMatch>
      <NightMatch>Aus Vs S A</NightMatch>
   </WC>
     <WC Group="B" Day="Sunday">
      <DayMatch>Eng VS NZ</DayMatch>
      <NightMatch>Pak Vs Zim</NightMatch>
   </WC>
   <WC Group="B" Day="Monday">
      <DayMatch>Pak VS Eng</DayMatch>
      <NightMatch>Zim Vs NZ </NightMatch>
   </WC>
</Cricket>
```

Now, i have give input   group A and Day Mondday, then i want ouput  Group A and monday full day and night game fixture this:

```
    Ind Vs Ban
    Aus Vs S A
```

Would you give any idea. How to access group and day value in xml.

Comment: Have you tried to search at least?

Answer (score 0):

declare id for each group. As per id and group name, you can write conditions on code.

Answer (score 0):

Parse this file with SAX Parser and put it in a list of WC model that you have to create like this `List<WC>` then search in this list